# Linq parent with multiple children

Tags: c#, linq

These are the tables I have

Parent

- ParentName
- ParentEmail
- ChildId1
- ChildId2
- SchoolId

Child

- ChildId
- ChildName

School

- SchoolId
- SchoolName

I want to pull parents data like this

```
ParentName, ParentEmail, SchoolName, ChildName1, ChildName2
```

How can I achieve this using Linq in C#?

I have tried this

```
var result = from parent
             join child
             join school
```

but it is not compiling.

Comment: A few questions/comments. What happens if a child has more than 1 parent, or if a parent has something other than 2 children. Nothing has a relationship with your "school" table. The code you show isn't close enough to C# LINQ code to call it C#. A `from` clause looks like `from p in parent`. A `join` always includes `on`

Comment: Thanks I missed typing the SchoolId in parent table. For this task, each parent has 2 children which go to same school.

Comment: As a suggestion, take a look at the answer that @carlobos provided.  See how he has enough code for you to understand what he's thinking, and for you to be able to get something running by simply copying that code into your project.  The next time you ask a question, try to get your question as well organized and as explicit (but still simple) as that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a linq query that will do what you're asking for. I do agree with @flydog57 related to your data structure. Unless you need to enforce the 2 kid rule, it would make a lot more sense to have a SchoolId, and Parent1 Parent2 on the Child table, rather than the other way around.

```
void Main()
{
    var parents = GetParents();
    var children = GetChildren();
    var schools = GetSchools();

    var child1parent = children.Join(parents, c => c.ChildId, p => p.Child1Id, (c, p) => new { Child = c, Parent = p });
    var child2parent = children.Join(parents, c => c.ChildId, p => p.Child2Id, (c, p) => new { Child = c, Parent = p });
    
    var results = child1parent
        .Join(child2parent, c1 => c1.Parent.Child2Id, c2 => c2.Child.ChildId, (c1, c2) => new { Parent = c1.Parent, Child1 = c1.Child, Child2 = c2.Child })
        .Join(schools, x => x.Parent.SchoolId, s => s.SchoolId, (x, s) => new { Parent = x.Parent, Child1 = x.Child1, Child2 = x.Child1, School = s })
        .Select(x => new { x.Parent, x.School, x.Child1, x.Child2 });

    results.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Parent.ParentName} {x.Parent.ParentEmail}, {x.School.SchoolName}, {x.Child1.ChildName}, {x.Child2.ChildName}"));
}

public class Parent
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public string ParentEmail { get; set; }
    public int Child1Id { get; set; }
    public int Child2Id { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
}

public List<Parent> GetParents()
{
    return 
        new List<Parent>
        {
            new Parent { ParentName = "Donald", ParentEmail = "donald@disney.com", Child1Id = 1, Child2Id = 2, SchoolId = 1 },
            new Parent { ParentName = "Lulubelle", ParentEmail = "Lulubelle@disney.com", Child1Id = 3, Child2Id = 4, SchoolId = 1 },
        };
}

public List<Child> GetChildren()
{
    return
        new List<Child>
        {
            new Child { ChildId = 1, ChildName = "Huey" },
            new Child { ChildId = 2, ChildName = "Dewey" },
            new Child { ChildId = 3, ChildName = "Fethry" },
            new Child { ChildId = 4, ChildName = "Abner" }
        };
}

public List<School> GetSchools()
{
    return
        new List<School>
        {
            new School { SchoolId = 1, SchoolName = "Disney School of Rock" }
        };
}
```